# select2 not selecting with no errors in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

The dropdown list renders properly but when clicked on a dropdown result, nothing happens. I know that select2 expects the results to be in a certain way but couldn't figure out why the results won;t get selected when clicked on the result in the dropdown. No errors or anything in the console..

The response from the REST service is an array of objects with Person details.

Here's a jsfiddle that I have setup to illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/qygpb1Lr/

```
            const $select2 = this.$element.find((`[rel='${this._interestedPartySelect2_id}']`));

            const formatResult = person => {

                if (!person || !person.FULL_NAME) return '';

                return `
                    <strong>${person.LAST_NAME}, ${person.FIRST_NAME}</strong> 
                    <br />
                    <i class='txt-color-cernerPurple'>${person.JOBTITLE || '--'}</i>
                    <br />
                    <span style="color:#525564">${person.DEPARTMENT || '--'}</span>
                    <br />
                    <span class='text-muted'>${person.INTERNET_E_MAIL || '--'}</span>
                `;
            };

            const formatSelection = person => {
                if (!person || !person.LAST_NAME || !person.FIRST_NAME) return '';

                return `${person.LAST_NAME}, ${person.FIRST_NAME}`;
            };

            $select2.select2({
                placeholder        : 'Enter Last Name',
                allowClear         : true,
                minimumInputLength : 3,
                query: query => {

                    $.ajax({
                        url    : `/remedy/people/last_name/${query.term}`,
                        type   : 'GET',
                        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
                        data   : JSON.stringify({ searchTerm: query.term })
                    })
                    .done(people => {

                        query.callback({ results: people });
                    });
                },
                formatResult,
                formatSelection,
                escapeMarkup    : m => m
            })
            .on('select2-removed', e => {
                // TODO
            })
            .on('select2-selecting', e => {
                console.log(e);  // TODO: Remove this
                if (e.object && e.object.PERSON_ID) {
                    console.log(e.object.PERSON_ID); // TODO
                }
            });
```

Comment: can you please provide a full example in jsfiddle or codepen or elsewhere :)

Comment: @HonsaStunna Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qygpb1Lr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this myself by passing an ID field to the select2 options like-so:

```
            $select2.select2({
                placeholder        : 'Enter Last Name',
                allowClear         : true,
                minimumInputLength : 3,
                id: obj      =>  obj.PERSON_ID,
                query: query => {

                    $.ajax({
                        url    : `/remedy/people/last_name/${query.term}`,
                        type   : 'GET',
                        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
                        data   : JSON.stringify({ searchTerm: query.term })
                    })
                    .done(people => {

                        query.callback({ results: people });
                    });
                },
                formatResult,
                formatSelection,
                escapeMarkup    : m => m
            })
            .on('select2-removed', e => {
                // TODO
            })
            .on('select2-selecting', e => {
                console.log(e);  // TODO: Remove this
                if (e.object && e.object.PERSON_ID) {
                    console.log(e.object.PERSON_ID); // TODO
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! Putting an id field in the object solved my problem.